# Check getExternalStorage() is real SD card

Tags: android

It's not clear to me how to be sure that when you call getExternalStorage(), you query the external SD-card or the internal memory of the phone. Is there a solution to check this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If there a case you want to do something different when it's a SD card?

Comment: From my own experience I have found that if it is the internal storage it is `/storage/sdcard0` and if it is an external sdcard it is usually `/storage/sdcard0/external_sdcard` Except in the case that there is no internal sdcard in which case the external sdcard is what you get from `Environment.getExternalStorage` This is generally because if the device has internal memory it is a mounted storage device. 

From this when I want to use an external sdcard I do `Environment.getExternalStorage` then check if `external_sdcard` is a directory in that file.

Comment: I want to give the user a choice: download an external (large) file to sd card or to internal memory... There's no logic in the name of  getExternalStorage(), on some devices it's the internal storage, on other devices it's the sd card...

Comment: `getExternalStorage()` always returns something that can be considered an SD card. On some phones it is emulated but I wouldn't consider calling this "internal memory". Although it might use the same physical memory, it is something different logically. There is no real use in giving the user the choice between a real SD card and an emulated one, espacially considering that afaik there is no phone that has both. You can give the user the choice between internal and external but don't use the emulated external storage under the term "internal memory".

Answer (score 2):

The method

```
 Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable()
```

should do what you want.

Disclaimer: I did not try that myself, just looked it up in the documentation.

Edit:

```
Environment.isExternalStorageEmulated()
```

may be useful as well.